# Difference between python command line and jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have completed an installation of libfreenect package python wrapper by using the setup.py from here:
https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/tree/master/wrappers/python

I ran setup.py from within conda environment, but the corresponding ipython kernel cannot import it. Upon importing, it says that the module cannot be found. When checking executable and path, I get the following:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable) 
print(sys.path)

/anaconda3/envs/p3.5/bin/python
['', '/anaconda3/envs/p3.5/lib/python35.zip', '/anaconda3/envs/p3.5/lib/python3.5', '/anaconda3/envs/p3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin', '/anaconda3/envs/p3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/anaconda3/envs/p3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/anaconda3/envs/p3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/Users/ognjenmilicevic/.ipython']
```

But from the command line I get no error:

```
/anaconda3/envs/p3.5/bin/python -c "import freenect"
```

How is this possible? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
After opening another terminal tab, "import freenect" fails however I call it, in conda environments or the main one. The command still works in the previous tab. I am even more confused now.

Comment: What's the output of `/anaconda3/envs/p3.5/bin/python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable); print(sys.path)"`?

Comment: Clever question!
['', '/anaconda3/envs/p3.5/lib/python35.zip', '/anaconda3/envs/p3.5/lib/python3.5', '/anaconda3/envs/p3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin', '/anaconda3/envs/p3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/anaconda3/envs/p3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages']

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, it turns out the setup.py created .so file win the current folder, so import only works in that folder. I didn't know this is possible, so I didn't take it into account.